# CakePHP paginate last page never ends

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a problem with the Cake (1.3) pagination limiter, here is the code:

```
$page = (!empty($this->params['form']['page'])) ? $this->params['form']['page'] : 1 ;

# Consulta        
$this->paginate = array('limit' => $limit, 'page' => 555, 'order' => array('Candidate.id' => 'ASC'), 'conditions' => $conditions);
$data = $this->paginate('Candidate');
```

When I send pages line 1,2,3, etc.. works OK, but if the result have 6 pages, and I send page 7, 8 or 999999 the query return to me the page 6, its correct?

I think the query send to me a empty array not the last page infinite.

Any method to force to send nothing when the page not exists?

Comment: I think this is correct and desirable behavior. It's better to see some content than no content at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how CakePHP pagination works.

If you want different behaviour you would have to capture the `$this->params['named']['page'];` value in the controller action and decide if it was an invalid number, then return the empty page you want rather than allowing CakePHP to use its default

For example

```
public function index() {

    $maxPage = 6; // need to calculate the max page value somehow

    if ($this->params['named']['page'] > $maxPage) {
        $rows = array();
    } else {
        $rows = $this->paginate('Model');
    }

    $this->set('rows', $rows);
}
```

Comment: Other method is allowed: $this->params['paging'][$Model]['pageCount'] return the page count, and now i make logic to "limit" the pagination.
But.. shit.. its not "logic" to see return data if the page dont contain data.. if i send page 999999 i can get "nothing" not the page 6 content. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 1.3, this is the default behaviour. This only changed per CakePHP 2.3, as the book [mentions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#out-of-range-page-requests):

> As of 2.3 the PaginatorComponent will throw a NotFoundException when trying to access a non-existent page, i.e. page number requested is greater than total page count.
>
> So you could either let the normal error page be rendered or use a try catch block and take appropriate action when a NotFoundException is caught.

If you really don't want unexisting pages to display anything, you can always add some custom code to your controller that renders an error page instead.